# while uploading excel sheet into sql getting error in ssis package

Tags: asp.net, excel, ssis, package

```
[SSIS.Pipeline] Warning: Warning: Could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL; data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, run this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.
[OLE DB Destination [450]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".
[OLE DB Destination [450]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (450) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (463). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

How to resolve this  serror .but i am trying to upload excel in windows server 2012 R2 that time i am getting this error.I am using sql server 2012.

Comment: Did you try running the package as an administrator or on the system's console?

Comment: No,Can you tell me how to run that package as an administrator or system's console.please refer anything.

Comment: i resolved this problem.some array's  is in that excel i removed that and  i run as a administrator.it executed successfully.